# How to remove program name from jpeg meta without changing dpi value?

Tags: jpeg, file-properties

Is there any way of removing the **Program Name** under **Origin** in **Details** tab from **Properties** without changing the **dpi value**?
Everything i tried until now changes the dpi from 300 (the value i've saved it) to 75 or 95.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this be cheating on a photography assignment? :)

Comment: what i change is my creation, i just want to change the source program to empty or something else. i can change it to gimp by saving it again but i'd like something easier like a stripper software or something alike

Comment: No, I meant presenting a tweaked photograph as untouched!

Comment: nah, as long as the image itself counts and not the program, i can make it thru gimp but i was wondering if there are any other easier/faster  ways of doing it